# Downloading music from Ubuntu one

Tags: music

I purchased some music which is now stored on Ubuntu One.  When I try to listen to it, it "stutters"!   So I would like to download these files to my HD to get better play quality but can find no mechanism to achieve this.  How do I do this, I'm sure it should be relatively simple, but I can't find how.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One FAQ:

> Where is the music I purchased from the Ubuntu One music store?
>
> You should also be able to see them in the web interface at
>   https://one.ubuntu.com/files/ in the Purchased Music folder. If you
>   can't, then please contact Ubuntu One support .
>
> If you want purchased music to download to your computer automatically
>   then make sure you have the "Purchased Music" folder checked in the
>   "Folders" tab of the Ubuntu One application. Once that is checked,
>   music will download to your computer.

[Source](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/where-is-the-music-i-purchased-from-the-ubuntu-one-music-store/)